# Show children onmouseover but on mouseoff hide the children

Tags: jquery

I trying to make a menu compatible with IE... :(

I did a menu using css that has this structure:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul id="menuu">
<li><a href="#" class="parent">Parent</a>
<ul class="children">
<li><a href="/#">name</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">name</a></li>
<li><a href="/#">name</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is:
-when mouse is over a.parent show children using fadeIn
-When you are off from Parent and also out from children, hide children.
-When you go in another children hide the previous children.

I did a script but I am not able to hide the children in the proper way.

```
<script>
$('a.parent').hover(function() {
    if( $(this).next().hasClass('children') ){
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    }else{
        //alert( 'false' );
    }
},
function() {
//here when you are out from a.parent

});
</script>
```

Because if I hide the children(submenu) when I'm out from the parent, I cannot open any link from children because when I move from parent to children, children is hiden..
So I don't know how to solve it... :(

Someone can help me??
Thank you very much!

Comment: Does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

How about blending the object with the background, instead of making it disappear?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('a.parent').bind('mouseover',function(){  
   $(this).addClass('hover');
   if($(this).next('ul').hasClass('children')){
      $(this).next('.children').addClass('expanded');         
     $(this).next('.children').stop().fadeIn();
    } else {
     //
    }
}).bind('mouseout',function(){
     $(this).removeClass('hover');
     if($(this).next('.children').not('.expanded'))
      {
         //If need be, you can add a delay here to make sure the mouse made it to 'children'
         $('.children').stop().fadeOut();
      }
})

$('.expanded').bind('mouseout',function(){
   $(this).removeClass('expanded');
   if($(this).prev('a').not('.hover')){
      $(this).stop().fadeOut();
    }
})
```

Comment: Also - others might disagree with me here - I think it is a good practice to avoid empty $(elem).next() statements, as the code can get confusing.  Unless there is a reason not to (like the selector is not known or ambiguous), I would always put the name of the selector that you are looking for as the argument for $(elem).next(), e.g. $(this).next('.children').

Comment: I'm sorry, I ran out of time to work on this.  Looks trickier than it first appeared.

Comment: Hi user1167442, Thank you very much for your time! no problem at all, I will try to find some other menu that works fine with this s*** of internet explore.Again, thank you :)